# How to define types for a numba dict

Tags: python, numba

I want to convert a python dict to a numba dict for speed reasons.  Here is my non-working MWE:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.normal(size=(3,3))

pyth_dict = {"A": 2, "B": mat}


@numba.njit()
def numbaize(pyth_dict):
    numba_dict = {}
    for key in pyth_dict.keys():
        numba_dict[key] = python_dict["B"]
    return numba_dict

numba_dict = numbaize(pyth_dict)
```

This doesn't work as I haven't specified the types.

My keys are strings and one of the keys has a corresponding integer value and the other a 2d numpy array as its value.

I should add that once the dict is made, it will never be modified. It is just used as a lookup table.  So the types of the keys, their names and the types of the values are all fixed and known in advance.

How can I specify the types correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to create a Numba dict which has multiple different types for the values. All of the examples I see online have only one type for all values. If the dict has fixed key names and types, you could perhaps use [jitclass](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html).

Comment: @NickODell It does have fixed key names and types.  I will add a comment to the question.

Comment: This is indeed not possible for Numba dict to contain values of different types. Jit classes are a solution indeed. An alternative solution is to use tuples. Something like `("A", 2, "B", mat)`. Note that strings are not efficient in Numba (especially unicode-based ones). Also note that the size of a tuple and the number of dimensions of an array are part of their types. Functions needs to be recompiled for each input types (like in all strongly-typed native languages).

Comment: Besides, AFAIK, the dict returned by Numba are converted to CPython ones (reflected lists) which are slow. I do not think this function is a good candidate for Numba. Numba is meant to be use for *numerical* computing (hence its name).

Comment: @JérômeRichard  My data won't change once it is loaded so the problem is that value types all have to be the same.  I don't understand using a tuple as looking up a value will then be a linear search of the keys won't it?   numba dicts do seem to be much faster than cpython ones according to my simple benchmarks.

Comment: @JérômeRichard How can I use a jit class for this?

Comment: Well you can just write a Python class with two fields A and B (and possibly add the related string constant in it). This assume the number of field is content which is implied by the fact values types are fixed at compiled time anyway. As a result, `numbaize` cannot iterate on the field because introspection is not supported by Numba AFAIK (like most native languages anyway -- D is the only one I know allowing that).